# MySQL: Combine multiple disparate tables into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple tables, say A, B, and C where B and C have a foreign key to A.

I want to write a query that will return a result set where the columns of the result set are the columns of A and B and C combined, i.e.

```
A.id A.name B.id B.name C.id C.name
-----------------------------------
1    Thing  2    Bee    NULL NULL
1    Thing  NULL NULL   1    Cow
```

That is, essentially a combination of the results of an individual LEFT OUTER JOIN on B and C, but combined into a single result set. I am ok with there being multiple NULL columns.

EDIT: The result set will always have the entries of A, but only ONE of either B or C.

Is this possible? Or is there a better way of joining this information?

Comment: Also do you want to show the matching rows of B and C in the same row or in different rows as shown in in you OP.

Comment: So you don't want `B` and `C` to be in the same row with their related `A`, but different rows for `A`?

Comment: I've tried chaining LEFT OUTER JOINs on multiple tables but, understandably, it doesn't give me the correct result set as it only returns matches.

Comment: Here, there could be no relation between B and C. Really, the ultimate result should always have the columns of A and one of either the columns of B or C, but never both B and C.

Comment: Ok that's more descriptive _A and one of either the columns of B or C, but never both_

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` along with JOINs to get to your result

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use UNION ALL because there's no guarantee that B and C have the same number of columns.

Comment: Wait, so the columns are variable too? You don't know all the columns of B and C ahead of time?

Comment: Sorry. I definitely know the columns of B and C, but B and C have different number of columns.

Comment: That should not matter as long as you are selecting only the ones you need and you know what cols you need in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you never want a single row to contain both `B` and `C`, you might `UNION` together two separate join queries, substituting `NULL` literals for the opposite table to get the columns to align.  Each part of the `UNION` supplies the relationship between `A->B` or `A->C`, but must return `NULL` for all the columns of the opposite table.  Supply a `NULL` literal to leave empty every column from the other table.

In the end to sort them, you can conditionally check that the `B` columns are `NOT NULL` to force the `B` row to sort ahead of the `C` row, after first ordering by `A.id`.

```
(
  SELECT 
    A.id AS a_id,
    A.name AS a_name,
    B.id AS b_id,
    B.name AS b_name,
    /* Substitute NULLs... for the other table C, for *all columns* */
    NULL AS c_id,
    NULL AS c_name,
    NULL AS other_c
    /* etc, other cols from C */
  FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
/* UNION, rather than UNION ALL  in case both tables have NULLs */
) UNION (
  SELECT
    A.id AS a_id,
    A.name AS a_name,
    /* This time substitute NULLs for B, again *all columns* */
    NULL AS b_id,
    NULL AS b_name,
    C.id AS c_id,
    C.name AS c_name
    C.other_c
  FROM A
    LEFT JOIN C ON A.id = C.a_id
)
ORDER BY 
  a_id,
  /* sort the non-null B ahead... */
  CASE WHEN b_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```